# How to respond to Sinch call in the background state?

Tags: ios, swift, voip, sinch, callkit

I use Sinch for audio calls also I use `CallKit`. I have a problem when the application is in the background state, I get a call to `CallKit` via `CXProviderDelegate`, but the sinch client does not have active incoming calls. Please, tell me how can I solve this problem?

```
final class ProviderDelegate: NSObject, CXProviderDelegate {

    private let provider: CXProvider

    static let shared = ProviderDelegate()

    private override init() {
        provider = CXProvider(configuration: type(of: self).providerConfiguration)

        super.init()

        provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    }


    /// The app's provider configuration, representing its CallKit capabilities
    static var providerConfiguration: CXProviderConfiguration {
        let localizedName = NSLocalizedString("App name", comment: "Name of application")
        let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: localizedName)

        providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = true

        providerConfiguration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1

        providerConfiguration.supportedHandleTypes = [.phoneNumber]

        if let iconMaskImage = UIImage(named: "IconMask") {
            providerConfiguration.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(iconMaskImage)
        }

        providerConfiguration.ringtoneSound = "Ringtone.aif"

        return providerConfiguration
    }

    // MARK: Incoming Calls

    /// Use CXProvider to report the incoming call to the system
    open func reportIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, handle: String, contactID: String, hasVideo: Bool = false, completion: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        // Construct a CXCallUpdate describing the incoming call, including the caller.
        let update = CXCallUpdate()
        update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: handle)
        update.hasVideo = hasVideo

        // Report the incoming call to the system
        provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { error in
            if error == nil {
                let call = SwiftlyChatCall(uuid: uuid, contactID: contactID)
                call.handle = handle

                SwiftlyChatCallManager.shared.addCall(call)
            }

            completion?(error)
        }
    }

    // MARK: CXProviderDelegate

    func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
        print("Provider did reset")

        AudioManager.shared.stopAudio()

        /*
         End any ongoing calls if the provider resets, and remove them from the app's list of calls,
         since they are no longer valid.
         */
        for call in SwiftlyChatCallManager.shared.calls {
            call.endSpeakerboxCall()
        }

        // Remove all calls from the app's list of calls.
        SwiftlyChatCallManager.shared.removeAllCalls()
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
        debugPrint("Provider, CXAnswerCallAction")
        guard SwiftlyChatCallManager.shared.callWithUUID(uuid: action.callUUID) != nil else {
            debugPrint("CXAnswerCallAction fail")
            action.fail()
            return
        }

        SinchManager.default.answerCall()

        // Signal to the system that the action has been successfully performed.
        action.fulfill()
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {
        guard let call = SwiftlyChatCallManager.shared.callWithUUID(uuid: action.callUUID) else {
            action.fail()
            return
        }

        debugPrint("CXEndCallAction", #function)
        SinchManager.default.cancelCall()

        // Signal to the system that the action has been successfully performed.
        action.fulfill()

        // Remove the ended call from the app's list of calls.
        SwiftlyChatCallManager.shared.removeCall(call)
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXSetHeldCallAction) {
        debugPrint("provider CXSetHeldCallAction")
        guard let call = SwiftlyChatCallManager.shared.callWithUUID(uuid: action.callUUID) else {
            action.fail()
            return
        }

        // Update the SpeakerboxCall's underlying hold state.
        call.isOnHold = action.isOnHold

        // Stop or start audio in response to holding or unholding the call.
        if call.isOnHold {
            AudioManager.shared.stopAudio()
        } else {
            AudioManager.shared.startAudio()
        }

        // Signal to the system that the action has been successfully performed.
        action.fulfill()

        // Remove the ended call from the app's list of calls.

        SwiftlyChatCallManager.shared.removeCall(call)
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, timedOutPerforming action: CXAction) {
        print("Timed out \(#function)")

        // React to the action timeout if necessary, such as showing an error UI.
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
        print("Received \(#function)")
        // Start call audio media, now that the audio session has been activated after having its priority boosted.
        SinchManager.default.callKitDidActive(provider, audioSession: audioSession)
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didDeactivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
        print("Received \(#function)")

        /*
         Restart any non-call related audio now that the app's audio session has been
         de-activated after having its priority restored to normal.
         */
    }

}


final class VOIPManager: NSObject {

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    static let `default` = VOIPManager()

    private let incomingCallIdentificator = "SIN_INCOMING_CALL"
    private let canceledIncomingCallIndentificator = "SIN_CANCEL_CALL"

    open func registration() {
        let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
        // Create a push registry object
        let voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)
        // Set the registry's delegate to self
        voipRegistry.delegate = self
        // Set the push type to VoIP
        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [.voIP]
    }

}

extension VOIPManager: PKPushRegistryDelegate {

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
        // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server
        guard type == .voIP else { return }
        SinchManager.default.registerDeviceToken(pushCredentials.token)
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didInvalidatePushTokenFor type: PKPushType) {
        guard type == .voIP else { return }
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        guard type == .voIP else { return }
        debugPrint("didReceiveIncomingPushWith")
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            guard var dict = payload.dictionaryPayload as? [String : Any] else { return }
            debugPrint("dict", dict)
            guard let sinString = dict["sin"] as? String else { return }
            guard let sinDict = sinString.toDictionary() else { return }
            dict["sin"] = sinDict
            guard let sinchIncomingCall = Mapper<SinchIncomingCallModel>().map(JSON: dict) else { return }
            let lockKey = sinchIncomingCall.aps.alert.locKey

            if lockKey == self.incomingCallIdentificator {
                self.incomingCallAction(sinchIncomingCall)
            } else if lockKey == self.canceledIncomingCallIndentificator {
                self.canceledIncomingCallAction(sinchIncomingCall)
            }
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - Actions

extension VOIPManager {

    private func incomingCallAction(_ sinchIncomingCall: SinchIncomingCallModel) {
        self.getDataForIncomingCall(sinchIncomingCall) { (contactID, phone) in
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
                self.displayIncomingCall(uuid: UUID(), handle: phone, contactID: contactID)
            }
        }
    }

    private func canceledIncomingCallAction(_ sinchIncomingCall: SinchIncomingCallModel) {
        self.getDataForIncomingCall(sinchIncomingCall) { (contactID, _) in
            SwiftlyChatCallManager.shared.end(contactID)
        }
    }

    private func displayIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, handle: String, contactID: String, hasVideo: Bool = false, completion: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        ProviderDelegate.shared.reportIncomingCall(uuid: uuid, handle: handle, contactID: contactID, hasVideo: hasVideo, completion: completion)
    }

    private func getDataForIncomingCall(_ sinchIncomingCall: SinchIncomingCallModel, completion: ((_ contactID: String, _ phone: String) -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            let contactsRealmManager = ContactsRealmManager()
            guard let contact = contactsRealmManager.getContact(sinchIncomingCall.sin.userID) else { return }
            let phoneNumber = contact.firstPhoneNumber() ?? ""
            completion?(contact.id, phoneNumber)
        }
    }


}
```

I also have `SinchManager` and it has this method

```
extension SinchManager {

    open func activeAudioSession(_ provider: CXProvider, audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
        sinch?.call().provider(provider, didActivate: audioSession)
    }

}
```

Comment: can you help me with the overall code?

Comment: @PratyushPratik Write your question, give a link to it, if I know I will write the answer.

Comment: I am adding sinch app to app call. My app to app call is working but I want to add call kit to it and I didn't able to find any sample code to add it. I tried it myself but it didn't worked. can you help me with some sample code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Alexander Hi Alex, sorry to trouble you and, first of all, I like to thank you to take the effort of getting CallKit to work in Swift code. I am kind of surprised and disappointed to see how little Swift support Sinch has offered. I am also deploying Sinch in my app and I can't code Obj-C even if my life is depending on it! I am wondering if you are happy to share your swift implement of Sinch CallKit? Really appreciated it if you can help out!

Comment: @cjensen Hi Christian, I am wondering if Sinch will supply Swift CallKit example soon? Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. I added this method to `SinchManager`

```
open func relayRemotePushNotification(_ userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let result = self.sinch?.relayRemotePushNotification(userInfo) else { return }
            guard result.isCall() else { return }
            debugPrint("result.isCall()", result.isCall())
        }
    }
```

and call this method here

```
   func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        guard type == .voIP else { return }
        debugPrint("VOIPmanager didReceiveIncomingPushWith")
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            SinchManager.default.relayRemotePushNotification(payload.dictionaryPayload)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the download package of Sinch iOS from [Sinch SDK download](https://www.sinch.com/docs/resources/downloads/index_vvv.html#sinchvvvdownloads), there is one reference implementation (Sinch CallKit sample App) which shows most use cases of handling incoming calls via CallKit framework. Please take a look there (though the sample app is still in Objc). If you have uploaded a valid VOIP push certificate for your App on Sinch portal, it should be fairly easy to install that App and play with it on your iPhone.

Below is a demo video of the CallKit sample App, for handling call in foreground, background and locked screen mode.

[Sinch CallKit App Demo Video](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AgfbTtGQOGvz4keHeB8GAb7hWysb)

Comment: there is no example in objective C as well please Bo Li can you please give me the objective C code or direct link to reach the code i will be thankfull for this. i have handle the call in background but when app kill i am fail to hanlde it

Comment: I have updated the Sinch Mobile SDK download url in the original answer above, please try again and download the package from "Voice SDK w/ Video" section